# Where should I store user statistics that need to be viewed frequently?

Tags: database-design, caching, statistics

In my web application, my users have many events.  One such event is "user updated facebook status."  A user could have hundreds of that type of event, and there are 10 types of events.  I need to display event counts and other user statistics based on events in a very scalable manner.  This is because each user will be able to see his or her statistics.  We obviously cannot afford to run each calculation every time a user hits the website so caching these statistics is certainly the way to go.

Does it make sense to create a separate table for "statistics" which would have a user id and a column for each statistic we are caching?  The table is essentially acting so I was wondering if there was a better or different way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just calculate these stats and put them in memcache, reading/incrementing them as required, as this data doesn't need to persist (there would be a server load spike from with a cold cache that you might consider rate limiting logins/calculations etc). However this scenario is an ideal candidate for a non-relational data stores such as [Cassandra](http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra/) (a "highly scalable, eventually consistent, distributed, structured key-value store"). [This internal Digg article](http://about.digg.com/blog/looking-future-cassandra) is a very interesting read:

> The fundamental problem is endemic to
>   the relational database mindset, which
>   places the burden of computation on
>   reads rather than writes. This is
>   completely wrong for large-scale web
>   applications, where response time is
>   critical. It’s made much worse by the
>   serial nature of most applications.
>   Each component of the page blocks on
>   reads from the data store, as well as
>   the completion of the operations that
>   come before it.
>
> Non-relational data stores reverse
>   this model completely, because they
>   don’t have the complex read operations
>   of SQL. The model forces you to shift
>   your computation to the writes, while
>   reducing most reads to simple
>   operations – the equivalent of SELECT
>   * FROM `Table`.

Comment: Cassandra is very interesting, thanks for the link.  I am researching

Comment: what is the this mean - "Each component of the page blocks on reads from the data store, as well as the completion of the operations that come before it."

Comment: The code is processed sequentially (i.e. line by line) so slow operations slow everything below them. "blocks on reads" means waits for the data to be returned.

Comment: Gotcha. It seems like Cassandra might be overkill for my situation because the main point seems to be preventing complex joins and read time.  In my case, I really just need to cache a count of each type of event.  For example, I have event type "user updated facebook status."  There may be 50 million rows in the event table and I need to query a COUNT by userid and event_type_id so I can say "this user registered this event 43 times"  So the problem is not so much a complicated query, but an expensive operation.  Do you think Cassandra is still worth consideration?